# increase every digit from string by 1

Tags: java

```
private static void getMethod(String input) {

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d)").matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb,
                String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

please explain the following lines....im not getting....

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
```

and

```
while (matcher.find()) {
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of those methods?

Comment: Hmm I personally kinda forgot was (\\d) means in regex... does it take the how does it take the parentheses into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
```

This is simple regexpr with group which gonna match number(groups are numered from 1 and groupe is specified by (), count starts from left side).

\d - short version of [0-9]

```
while (matcher.find()) {
```

This is simple loop over all numbers in string. This part gonna match number and put it in group.

```
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
```

This one is little bit harder.

It puts all chars from matched string into sb, and replaces part of at which it stopped.

```
String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1)
```

This takes string version of number(matched by find) parses it to int, add 1, and parses back to String

Sory for any lexical mistakes